# How to create a multidimensional Array to take input from .txt file and store the strings and the numbers separate

Tags: java, file, text, multidimensional-array, input

```
public class ArrayDirectory {
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String file = ("lab4b2.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    // initialises the scanner to read the file file

    String[][] entries = new String[100][3];
    // creates a 2d array with 100 rows and 3 columns.

    int i = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        entries[i] = scan.nextLine().split("\t");
        i++;
    }
    //loops through the file and splits on a tab

    for (int row = 0; row < entries.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < entries[0].length; col++) {
            if(entries[row][col] != null){
                System.out.print(entries[row][col] + " " );
            }
        }
        if(entries[row][0] != null){
             System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
    //prints the contents of the array that are not "null"
 }
}
```

How do I make the following code to split the string into pieces and store them in the multidimentional array? For example:

Text:

123 abc 456

789 def 101 112

array

[123] [abc] [456]

[789] [def] [101] [112]

The numbers from the text being converted to numbers before stored in the array. I believe I have to use Integer parsed.Int(). not sure how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following corrections, you would end up with the entries array with the splitted strings correctly.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException 
{

String file = ("C:\\array.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
// initialises the scanner to read the file file

String[][] entries = new String[100][3];
// creates a 2d array with 100 rows and 3 columns.

int i = 0;
while(scan.hasNextLine())
{
    String [] splittedEntries = new String[3];
    splittedEntries = scan.nextLine().split(" ");

    for( int inx = 0; inx < splittedEntries.length; ++inx )
    {
        entries[i][inx] = splittedEntries[inx];
    }
    i++;

}
}
```

At this moment, your entries array would look like this:

```
entries[0] = { 123, abc, 456 };
entries[1] = { 789, def, 101 };
```

So, you can write your own loops now and process as required.

Comment: Thanks. I get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at mainmethod.MainMethod.main(MainMethod.java:55)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Also etries[1] has to have 4 elements

Comment: That is because your second input has 4 entries. Take a look at this one: 789 def 101 112. And your first entry has only 3 entries: 123 abc 456.
So, either this has to be corrected, or use entries[100][4].

Comment: You are using arrays. The size of the number of elements in the arrays has to be the same. And this size should be equal to the largest size of a row in your input. If a particular row has 5 elements, your entries should be entries[100][5]. I am hoping you are getting the point.

Comment: The idea is that the some of the input lines will have 3 elements and some 4, when broken down and stored in the array. It shows the same error when I do entries[100][4]                                                                                            run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at mainmethod.MainMethod.main(MainMethod.java:31)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Good to know. If it works with 5, then it means that there is a line in your file which has 5 entries in it and it is the line with the maximum number of entries.

Comment: I think 5 is basically 4, because when you declare the array with 5 elements it fills elements 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  and then the loop is executing till it reaches array.length. That's what was throwing me off, trying to display it.